# Access model data throught req.body after a fetch() call

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I would like to know if i do something wrong or if it's normal that i can't access the properties of my model on the server side (using express) by calling `req.body.username` (for example) after a fetch() call:

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.username); //Undefined
});
```

But i can access it the same way by a PUT request.

Actually i used the url to send the username but i would like to clean my routes and access the properties throught `req.body` instead, (of course after setting it in my model on the client side).

Thanks for the explanation !

UPDATE:

In case it could matter, here is my app configuration:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({secret: 'test', store: express.session.MemoryStore({
    reapInterval: 60000 * 10
 })}));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you use backbone.js on the client, as you've tagged your question with it. Backbone's [sync-method](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-179) by default doesn't seem to attach the model data to the request. You could pass it in as an option to fetch/sync, but it seems [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) would append the data to the url anyway. You'd probably have to override backbone's sync- and/or ajax-method. I believe it is against REST-principals to include a body in a GET-request though, as indicated in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/178419) (a resource has to be completely identified by the URI).